# How to run script on specific sheet and insert a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new and started learning to code this year.

I am trying to insert a formula into a specific sheet. The script is working and I am able to insert a new row and the formula, however the script runs even when I edit a different sheet. I only want it to run when cell A2 is edited on "Test" sheet.

Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    insertRow(e);
    copyFormulas(e);

    function insertRow(e) {
        // get sheet
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test");

        // Get the edited range
        var editedRange = e.range;

        if (editedRange.getA1Notation() === "A2") {
            // check 
            sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
        }
    }
    
    function copyFormulas(e) {
        SpreadsheetApp
        .getActive()
        .getSheetByName('Test')
        .getRange('C3')
        .setFormula("=SUM(A3*B3)");
    }
}
```

LINK to the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AhwnzyKf6dSPHGKUPNuniZ0gtTihPDLaqAyEtAjNn8A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this task, your code can be shortened to the following form

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range,
      sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Test' && range.getA1Notation() == 'A2' ){
    sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
    sheet.getRange('C3').setFormula("=SUM(A3*B3)");
  }
}
```

You can find a lot of useful information by reading the documentation on [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) , or simply by searching for [onEdit(e)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=onedit%28e%29) on this site

I would add, **sometimes** instead of increasing the amount of formulas on the sheet (which causes the whole table to slow down), it is recommended to use an array formula that works for the whole column, and that you don't have to duplicate on every row.
In the case of your table, instead of adding a formula every time you insert a row with the following code `sheet.getRange('C3').setFormula("=SUM(A3*B3)")` - it is better to use one array formula in cell `C1` `={"Col3";ArrayFormula(if(A2:A<>"",A2:A*B2:B,))}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I am definite going to use the array formula. Thank you for the cool links I have learnt allot!